# Correct type for a top 10 photographers list

Tags: schema.org

I recently bing through lot of reading about JSON-LD structured data types for my website which list the top 10 photographers in each city in my country. I'm struggling to find a correct data type for this.

Currently, my choice is `ListItem`. I wanna know is that the correct one and on that type there are a lot of variations I wanna know the perfect one.

Comment: If you can't find an appropriate schema, it is fine not to use any.   Can you elaborate as to why you want one?   Did somebody ask you to provide a way to digest your content in a machine readable way?

Comment: yes, it is important to have json-ld on a website in order to get a better result in a google search.  no someone it is google encourages us to put structure data on our website.

Comment: It doesn't work that way.   You can't just use a structured data and expect to get a ranking boost.   Google doesn't adjust rankings based on the presence of schema.   The only benefit to using a schema for Google is using one that Google supports for changing the display of your site in the search results.   They have a gallery here: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/search-gallery   If it isn't in that list, it won't do anything for Google.

Comment: Ok, what should I do to increase my rank?  I have good contents, everyone says that always, but good contents doesn't seem to work well.  what are your suggestions?

Comment: See: [What are the best ways to increase a site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google)

Answer (score 1):

If it's a listicle, it's still under the "article" type. I suggest you also create a page for each of this photographer and assign it as "local business" and refer these pages on your "listicle" article

Comment: yes, that is the correct way. I created separate pages and in list items, i refer those pages.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the listItem schema can be used in this way.

It is unclear right now if this will change, but you can house Schema of other types withn the listitem schema and it can also be used to lists of items like products, food, movies, etc

Google will use this to better understand a list of items even though it isn't detailed in their featured Schema guides. I've seen many example of this coming up in SERPs too in list form.

I've also seen it work for Product Schema on a category page. Detailing a list of products as a category grouping of items. Each product schema then falls within the itemlist elements one at a time.

I've also seen it work for a list of different types of food items.

Schema DOES influence rankings. In fact, i've seen several demonstrations of elements of Schema influencing rankings where the content is not on the front end. Schema is crawled before other content and is included in the information Google uses to rank websites.This has been repeatedly demonstrated and tested by ranking for keywords within Schema elements that are not on-page.

Comment: Can you share your sources for ranking influence of schema?